LuaScript/LuaLaTeX for reproduceable hex random numbers
Edited and shortened
For my documentation, I want to have/draw a memory layout with random hex numbers - so that it doesn't get so boring with multiple images. To this end, I created a Lua script that generates a series of these numbers as hex strings for later use. The hex-number must equal to a byte with 2 digits, ranging from 0 to 255. The idea is to store them permanently in a LaTeX variable and then use them with an index so that the same index gives the same number in the document/unit.
This question related to Lua (since I'm using lualatex) is complementary to the TikZ for reproduceable hex random numbers question.
Here my Lua script stored on file system:
random = {}

function random.hexBytes(count)
    io.write("Generate " .. count .. " bytes: ")
    bytes = {}
    for i = 1, count+1 do
        bytes[i] = string.format("%02X", math.random(0, 255))
        io.write(bytes[i] .. ", ")
    end
    io.write("\n")

    return bytes
end

return random

which is used by my LaTeX in that way:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{chains, scopes}

\begin{document}

\directlua{rand = require("figures/scripts/random")}

\newcommand{\randHexBytes}[1]{%
    \directlua{
        local bytes = rand.hexBytes(16*4)
        print('LaTeX (index) arg: ' .. #1)
        tex.print(bytes[#1+1])
    }
}

\begin{figure}[t]

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\sffamily,
    node distance = 0mm and 20mm,
    start chain = R going below,
    N/.style = {draw,fill=yellow!20,
                minimum height=5mm,
                outer sep=0pt, text opacity=1, align=center}
  ]
  \begin{scope}[nodes=on chain=D]
    \tikzset{
        minimum width={width("0xAA BB CC DD")+2pt}
    }
    \foreach \r in {0,1,...,15}{
        \ifnum\r<7
            \node[on chain=R, N] {\texttt{0x\randHexBytes{\r*4}\randHexBytes{\r*4+1}\randHexBytes{\r*4+2}\randHexBytes{\r*4+3}}};
        \else
            \ifnum\r=9
                \node[on chain=R, N, text=blue] {\texttt{0xAA}};
            \else
                \node[on chain=R, N] {\texttt{0x\randHexBytes{\r*4}\randHexBytes{\r*4+1}\randHexBytes{\r*4+2}\randHexBytes{\r*4+3}}};
            \fi
        \fi
    }
  \end{scope}
  \node[above] at (R-1.north west) {MSB};
  \node[above] at (R-1.north east) {LSB};
  %% check the persistent random numbers during latex run, eg.g line #3
  \node[N] at (R-16) {\#3: \texttt{0x\randHexBytes{3*4+0}\randHexBytes{3*4+1}\randHexBytes{3*4+2}\randHexBytes{3*4+3}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\centering
\caption{My use case}
\label{fig:hexblk}
\end{figure}

My intend is to use the same Hex Numbers everywhere, so that can I refer to
them in the text, like: The 3rd row in \ref{fig:hexblk} holds
\texttt{0x\randHexBytes{3*4+0}\randHexBytes{3*4+1}\randHexBytes{3*4+2}\randHexBytes{3*4+3}}
as expected.
\end{document}

and results into:

... or not as expected. As you can see, the hex number taken is not intentional - each reference to the 3rd line should contain the same numbers. During LaTeX run, I can see the generation of new numbers by the Lua processor in the terminal. The hex string array as a LaTeX macro is created each time instead of doing it once to be able to access it in the document.
How can I generate a persistent list of hex (string) numbers with Lua script (like mine) and refer back to it? I'm also interested in a better API for accessing it, maybe to avoid calculating e.g. 3*4+1 (4-byte alignment) every time in the TikZ node.

Please keep to the one question per question rule. I know why you get the extra space. But I know zilch about Lua. So I can't really answer.

Here is a MWE where I have used the math.randomseed function in Lua to set a random seed (I have set it to be 1234).

-- saved in random.lua
random = {}

function random.hexBytes(count, seed)
    bytes = {}
    math.randomseed(seed)
    for i = 1, count+1 do
        bytes[i] = string.format("%02X", math.random(0, 255))
    end
    
    return bytes
end

return random


% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}


\directlua{
rand = require("random")
local bytes = rand.hexBytes(16*4, 1234)  % set the random seed
}

\newcommand{\randHexBytes}[1]{%
    \directlua{
    tex.print(bytes[#1+1])
    }% <- this is important; otherwise you get a spurious space
}

\begin{document}
\randHexBytes{0}
\end{document}


Changing the preamble and random.lua and running your code will show that it is in fact the 4th line that you refer to in the text, not the 3rd, (0*4 + 0 is the first, 1*4 + 0 is the second, ..., 3*4+0 is the fourth row), but other than this, it works as you want it to.
Regarding the better API, one thing you could do is simply make \randHexBytes take 2 arguments, and then index the array at the 4*#1 + #2 + 1:
\newcommand{\randHexBytes}[2]{%
    \directlua{
    tex.print(bytes[4*#1 + #2 + 1])
    }%
}

Another option is to have something of the form \randHexBytes{1,2} where you split on the comma and so on. String split seems to not be a pre-defined function in Lua, but you can find examples here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin

So the idea behind is to use a seed to get reproducible numbers, isn't it? Thank you, you pointed out the correct use of (slice) index, which I wasn't aware in my LaTeX source yet (4*#1 for the 'base' address/index)
